# How do I add custom section to a build summary in TFS Build 2015?

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I can see that in previous versions of TFS Build it's been possible to [add a custom section to the build summary screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.writecustomsummaryinformation(v=vs.120).aspx), but I've been unable to find anything for 2015... has anyone done this for the latest version of TFS Build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new build summary displays on the web portal. Currently, these customizations are not supported.

> You can submit it to User Voice site at: 
>   http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `task.uploadsummary` logging command to upload a markdown file:

```
##vso[task.uploadsummary]mySummaryInfo.md
```

Basically you would need to generate whatever summary information you want into a markdown-formatted file, then write the above logging command to stdout, substituting the correct file name.  The VSTS Build (now called Azure Pipelines) logging mechanism will see the logging command, look for the file, and add the markdown to the summary page.

As of this writing, the documentation can be found here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Powershell script to write a custom logging commands.

Example (from the GitHub page):

```
The general format for a logging command is:

##vso[area.action property1=value;property2=value;...]message
To invoke a logging command, simply emit the command via standard output. For example, from a PowerShell task:

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"
```

Full documentation is on the [vsts-task GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).